# Border not showing up

Tags: html, css, styling

I am pretty new to CSS borders, and i have run into some issues i don't seem to be able to fix. As im new to this, and there is propably many other wondering the same thing (of css newbies). I have this border that should work fine, according to my thinking (might be full of wrong-ish logic). The code i use for the hover and default state is:

```
.profile-box .opener {
    float:left;
    background: url(http://seek4fitness.net/Design/Gfx/DropDowns/white.on.red/icn_small_black_arrow_down.gif) no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-color: #fff;
    width:32px;
    height:38px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
        border-left:1px solid #dde2e8;
}
.profile-box .opener:hover {
    float:left;
    background: url(http://seek4fitness.net/Design/Gfx/DropDowns/white.on.red/icn_small_black_arrow_down.gif) no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
    width:32px;
    height:38px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
        border-left:1px solid #dde2e8;
}
```

The issue do not appear to me in any way, and im as said twice, new to css. Please help me with this. It will mean a lot to me. Thanks.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/dCe3u/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is great for setting up stuff like this so others can tinker with it. As it stands, there isn't anything *obviously* wrong (to me at least)

Comment: FYI, you don't have to repeat style declarations in the `:hover` state. All you need to have is `background-color: #F0F0F0;`

Comment: Added fiddle. Should have done it earlier.

Comment: What, exactly, is the issue?

Comment: I see a border. Everything looks as expected... What browser are you using? Or what did you expect to see?

Comment: in fiddle it's working fine

Comment: what is your problem?? border not showing?? but i can see a left border in your fiddle

Comment: I expected a border all around it.

Comment: then use just `border` instead of `border-left`

Comment: then use `border:1px solid #dde2e8;` not `border-left`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dCe3u/3/

Comment: Using just border makes it not display right. Im not sure why.

Comment: define "not display right"; it looks *ok* to me. One thing to be aware of, `border` __adds__ to the `width` and `height` of an element - so your element is 34x40 here, not 32x38

Comment: When i use any of your answers i get the whole element positioned some pixels further down than supposed to. Any ideas what could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply border to **all the four sides** you should change

```
border-left:1px solid #dde2e8;
```

**to**

```
border:1px solid #dde2e8;
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dCe3u/1/)**

border-left will apply border only to the left side, You can refer more on border here **[CSS BORDER >>](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code. I literally copy and paste your code and the border does appear, I think the problem is the color of the border is too light (if you use white background). See the demo http://codepen.io/ImBobby/pen/yicCz. In that demo I intentionally change the border color to red.

I also notice that you declared same style on hover state of `.opener` element except for the background-color. You might want to change your code into this:

```
.opener {
    float: left;
    background: url(http://seek4fitness.net/Design/Gfx/DropDowns/white.on.red/icn_small_black_arrow_down.gif) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: #fff;
    ...
}

.opener:hover {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

short explanation, `.opener:hover` will inherit styles from `opener`.